# Different estimates between bam and gam model (mgcv) and interaction term estimates edf of 0

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, bam

I am new to fitting gamm models and ran into two problems with my analysis.

1. I ran the same model using the gam and the bam function of the package mgcv. The models give me different estimates, and I don't understand why and how to choose which function to use. Can anyone explain to me why these functions give different estimates?
2. I am estimating a model including an interaction between age and condition (binomial factor with 2 conditions). For some reason one of the interaction terms (age:conditioncomputer or age:conditioncozmo) looks weird. It always gives a EDF and chi square of 0 and a p-value of 0.5, as if it was fixed to that. I tried using sum-to-zero and dummy contrasts, but that did not change the output. What is weird to me that there is a significant age effect, but this effect is not significant in neither condition. So I have the strong feeling that something is going wrong here.

Did anyone ever run into this before and can help me figure out if this is even a problem or normal, and how to solve it if it is a problem?

My model syntax is the following:

```
`bam(reciprocity ~ s(age,k=8) + condition + s(age, by = condition, k=8) + s(ID, bs="re") + s(class, bs="re") + s(school, bs="re"), data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))`
```

This is the model output:

[image]

My df looks somewhat like this:

[image]

In short, I've used below code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)
library(rstatix)
library(car)
library(yarrr)
library(itsadug)
df <- read.csv("/Users/lucaleisten/Desktop/Private/Master/Major_project/Data/test/test.csv", sep=",")

df$ID <- as.factor(as.character(df$ID))
df$condition <- as.factor(df$condition)
df$school <- as.factor(df$school)
df$class <- as.factor(df$class)
df$reciprocity <- as.factor(as.character(df$reciprocity))
summary(df)

model_reciprocity <- bam(reciprocity ~ s(age,k=7) +condition + s(age, by = condition, k=7) + s(ID, bs="re") + s(class, bs="re") + s(school, bs="re"), data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model_reciprocity)
```

Comment: You can't get a smooth of age that is independent of the two conditional smooths on age.  If you take the first `s(age, k=8)` out, I bet you'll get "good" estimates for the two conditional smooths.

Comment: Thanks Dave! That indeed solved it! I assumed gamms are similar to linear mixed models where you also estimate the main effect, but your explanation makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @DaveArmstrong In general I believe you can do this! I would first evaluate in some way whether you need both smooths. In these models there may be an issue with concurvity. It often helps if you penalize different derivatives for the global smooth and the "by" smooth, for example, this paper 10.7717/peerj.6876 recommends placing the penalty on the first derivative of the "by" term (your model currently has penalties on the second derivative of each)

Comment: @SushiChef you're right; I hadn't seen that paper.  Perhaps Luca needs to use a different smoothing basis for this to work?

Comment: Something looks wrong here. I would have assumed that the entry in the Parametric coefficients table would be listed as `conditioncozmo`, not `condition1`. I also don't know why the p value is being displyed like that, nor how you get an EDF below 1 for the GAM model being shown - even though as @SushiChef mentions you really need `m=1` on the factor `by` smooths to make this all identifiable.

Comment: Hi all, first of all thanks for the help! I looked at the paper @DaveArmstrong recommended and I think that might shed some light here. I do have another question though and maybe you can help. My model (without the main effect of age) now gives me two marginally significant effects for age:computer and age:cozmo. I also ran the same model on a subset of just cozmo condition and just human condition (without effect of condition). I get a significant age effect in the cozmo subset. How is it possible that I get a significant effect there, but not for age:cozmo in the model with both conditions?

Comment: @Luca the subset models are essentially interacting everything with the subsetting condition.  As such, all sorts of things can change.

Comment: @Dave Ah I see! So in that case I guess it is better to trust the full model instead of trying running independent models, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, just be mindful of the fact that by splitting the data and running separate models that it implies an a set of interactions that you may or may not want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the official documentation of `bam`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.9-0/topics/bam), I surmise that `gam` is the more rigorous, accurate function. You should generally always use it. However, for large datasets, `gam` can be very slow. (For example, I ran `gam` on a dataset with 20000 rows × 70 predictors on a decently fast computer and I gave up after it just kept running for over 24 hours--I terminated the process.) **`bam`** is implemented differently so that it can run much more efficiently on large datasets, but, as far as I can tell, it seems to do so by taking a few shortcuts that mean that its results are less stable than gam on the same dataset. That said, for very large datasets, the differences are apparently so minimal that bam should be sufficiently reliable.

My understanding is based on [the official documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.9-0/topics/bam):

```
WARNINGS

The routine may be slower than optimal if the default "tp" basis is used.
This routine is less stable than `gam' for the same dataset.
With discrete=TRUE, te terms are efficiently computed, but t2 are not.

Details
When discrete=FALSE, bam operates by first setting up the basis characteristics for the smooths, using a representative subsample of the data. Then the model matrix is constructed in blocks using predict.gam. For each block the factor R, from the QR decomposition of the whole model matrix is updated, along with Q'y. and the sum of squares of y. At the end of block processing, fitting takes place, without the need to ever form the whole model matrix.

… For full method details see Wood, Goude and Shaw (2015).

Note that POI is not as stable as the default nested iteration used with gam, but that for very large, information rich, datasets, this is unlikely to matter much.
```